# Sending array of struct from c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, dllimport, unmanaged

I am trying to send an array of simple struct from c# to a c++ DLL and to get the size elements of the array.

My c++ code is:

```
struct TestStruct
{
    int m_Int;
};

unsigned int _declspec(dllexport) __stdcall GetSysData(LPSAFEARRAY FAR* ppsaFiles)
{
 return (*ppsaFiles)->rgsabound[1].cElements;
}
```

My c# code is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct InnerStruct
{
  public int m_Int;
}

[DllImport("DimMonitorDll.dll", EntryPoint = "GetSysData", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int GetSysData([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ref InnerStruct[] x);

public void run()
{
   InnerStruct[] test_struct;
   test_struct = new InnerStruct[5];
   var count = GetSysData(ref test_struct);
}
```

The problem is that I get count = 0 .
I have tried many things I found on the web, but I didn't success to figure it out.
I will appreciate any help,
Thanks!

Comment: Why does the C++ code use a `SAFEARRAY`? Seems like there is no need for that. Why does the C# code set `Pack = 1`. That looks wrong, and a bad idea. Marshalling simple structs is quite trivial. Why all the complexity.

Comment: I can't change the c++ code, it's a library I must work with. Removing the Pack=1 not helping fixing the issue.

Comment: Step back. Why did you add `Pack = 1`? You are just trying stuff at random aren't you? Do you really believe that `Pack = 1` is correct? Why? The fact that you have many errors means that fixing one isn't enough. The fact that fixing one of your many errors is not enough does not mean that what you just fixed was correct. Now, if you must pass a `SAFEARRAY`, do that. `LPArray` is not `SAFEARRAY`. Do some research on marshalling `SAFEARRAY`.

Comment: Already done that but using UnmanagedType.SafeArray giving throws System.ArgumentException

Comment: OK, I don't really want to help anymore, because you seem to be in headless chicken try stuff at random mode. That's never fun on our side of the deal.